# Cannot resolve module

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Complete react newb here.  I am having a really stupid issue trying to use components.  When i have the components in the index.js (entry file) it works fine with import.  however when i try to reference it from another component it ONLY tries to resolve the path from the parent component.

```
Root
  - Example/Example.js
  - Test/Test.js

/*  In Test.js  */
var Test= React.createClass({
    render() {
        return <div>
            "Hello"
        </div>
    }
});
export default Test;


/*  In Example.js */
import Test from './Test/Test';
var Example = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return <div>
            <Test />
        </div>
    }
});
export default Example;
```

Now i get error:
Cannot resolve module './Test/Test' in G:\app\root\example <--- here it only looks in the root.

I think its a webpack issue? I have tried the docs and suggestions for adding resolve.root but that didnt seem to help.  Being a newb I am not sure if the issue is react or webpack or where to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your path to Test is incorrect. It should be `../Test/Test`

Comment: No problem. Sometimes all it takes is an extra eye

Comment: Yea i had to wait to accept the answer, SO wont allow you mark it until after some time period - thanks